# Oracle Sql developer how to display null foreign key

Tags: oracle, null

I am doing Oracle database project which called "Theatre booking system".
I am trying to display discounted price through Customer_Concession and Member_Concession.
Null-able foreign keys are bookingId, cconcessionId, and mconcessionId in Ticket table.
I want to display all ticket even one of id is not exist.
How can I write the SQL?
Could you help me?
Thanks.

```
SELECT t.ticketId, pro.name "Production name", PRICE.LEVELID "Price level", 
Price.price "Price", (Price.price - ccons.discountPrice - mcons.discountPrice)
"Discounted Price", t.seatNo "Seat", t.rowNo "Row", t.block "Block",
per.performance_date "Performance date", per.start_time "Start time", 
per.end_time "End time", t.availability "Availability"

FROM Ticket t, Production pro, Performance per, Price, Price_level, 
Booking, Customer, Customer_Concession ccons, Member_concession mcons

WHERE t.performanceid = per.performanceid AND
  t.PRODUCTIONID = Price.PRODUCTIONID AND
  t.levelId = Price.levelId AND
  Price.PRODUCTIONID = pro.PRODUCTIONID AND
  Price.levelId = Price_level.levelId AND
  t.bookingId = Booking.bookingId AND
  Booking.customerId = Customer.customerId AND
  ccons.cconcessionId = t.cconcessionId AND
  mcons.mconcessionId = t.mconcessionId

ORDER BY t.ticketId
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called LEFT OUTER JOIN.

for more info, visit this site: http://www.oreillynet.com/network/2002/04/23/fulljoin.html

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
WHERE t.performanceid = per.performanceid AND
      t.PRODUCTIONID = Price.PRODUCTIONID AND
        t.levelId = Price.levelId AND
        Price.PRODUCTIONID = pro.PRODUCTIONID AND
        Price.levelId = Price_level.levelId AND
        t.bookingId = Booking.bookingId(+) AND
        Booking.customerId = Customer.customerId(+) AND
        ccons.cconcessionId(+) = t.cconcessionId AND
        mcons.mconcessionId(+) = t.mconcessionId
```

(note old syntax)